# Problems signing a dll in F# on Mono

Tags: f#, mono, assembly-signing

I'm getting an error trying to sign a dll in F# on mono:

```
$ mono /usr/local/share/FSharp-2.0.0.0/bin/fsc.exe\
   --target:library \
   --keyfile:../../external/MyKeyFile.snk\
   AssemblyInfo.fs\
   ../../fs/FooBar.fs\  
   -o:FooBar.dll
```

No dll is generated, and I get this error back:

```
Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Compiler build 2.0.0.0 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.`

error FS2014: A problem occurred writing the binary '': A call to StrongNameGetPublicKey failed (mscoree.dll)`
```

The keyfile was generated in Windows, does that make any difference?

**Update:**

Using Mono 2.6.4

```
$ mono --version 

Mono JIT compiler version 2.6.4 (tarball Mon Jun 21 19:26:21 UTC 2010) 
Copyright (C) 2002-2010 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
TLS:           __thread
GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
SIGSEGV:       altstack
Notifications: epoll
Architecture:  amd64
Disabled:      none
```

Comment: Which version of Mono are you using? (you can find out with mono --version)

Comment: @Edgar, I've added the info to the question.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like fsc is P/Invoking native Windows API, which is not portable. You should probably raise the issue with the F# team.

Comment: @Benjol: did you hear anything?

Comment: @mmacaulay, not really, I think I got copied on an 'internal' mail saying they'd try and look into it. I suspect it's somewhere in the no-man's land between Microsoft and Mono... But if/when I **do** hear anything, I'll post here.

Answer (score 2):

Try using sn to sign after you generate the assembly.

To do this you first need to compile with the [--delaysign flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233171.aspx) to produce a delay signed assembly.

You can then use the [sn](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/sn.1.html) utility with the -R flag to sign the assembly afterward.

I'm not 100% sure this will work as I don't have a Linux or Mac machine around to test it on.  It's worth a shot though.

Comment: I've looked and can't work out how to sign a previously unsigned assembly... Any pointers welcome...

Comment: I added more info.  Hope this helps.